# PLSQL trigger or any other way to maintain primary criteria for insert statements

Tags: oracle, plsql, primary-key, database-trigger

I need help for trigger or something like that.

Problem is:

I have a table with "id" as primary key. 
The file which I get from a third party application contains only insert statements to the table (File generation happens in regular basis).
When I execute the file (File contains new as well as existing IDs), 
a) record should be inserted to table for new ID 
b) delete-insert or update should be happened for existing IDs

Comment: Create a view from this table and an INSTEAD OF TRIGGER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way would be to change the insert statements to [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#SQLRF01606) statements. However, when you say "*which I get from a third party application ...*" then I assume you cannot changes them.

In this case create a view from your table, i.e. a simple `CREATE VIEW ... AS SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE;`

Then you can create ab [INSTEAD OF Trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG52800), for example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_name_view_trigger
INSTEAD OF UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE ON ...
BEGIN

  IF INSERTING THEN
     MERGE INTO ... D
     USING (SELECT :new.ID, :new.x, :new.Y, :new.Z FROM dual) S
       ON (D.ID = S.ID)
     WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ...
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ...;
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
     NULL; -- do nothing for delete
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
     UPDATE ... SET ...
     WHERE ID = :OLD.ID;
END;
```

Comment: So I need to change the SQL insert statements file to point to the view instead of table . Am i correct ?

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a script which contains `INSERT` statements, but only new data should be INSERTED, and updates should be 'upserted'.

The immediate response is to replace the INSERT statements with `MERGE` statements, which might be possible using `sed + awk` but without seeing the scripts and table formats we don't know.

Or another approach would be to `grep` for the `ID` values in the script, and generate a block of `DELETE`s for these prior to the `INSERT`s.

Again, without a sample of code from your script I cannot give any code on how you'd do this.

A somewhat more elaborate approach might be as follows, assuming your table is called `the_app_table`:

```
-- CREATE A table based on INSERT target

CREATE TABLE the_temp_table AS SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE 1 = 2;
```

Now sed the file to change the target name to the temp table:

`sed 's/the_target_table/the_temp_table/' the_script.sql > the_new_script.sql`

Run this new script, which will INSERT the data into the temp table.

The write a single `MERGE` statement to UPSERT from `the_temp_table` to `the_app_table`.